# Unable to fetch redirected URL using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to selenium and java. I have redirected my page from Login to Dashboard for a site. But when the current url is fetched it gives me the url of login page.

However, when I use the below code, it fetches the url of Dashboard(redirected page):
driver.navigate().refresh();
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

Please suggest the correct approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below example and I am able to fetch redirected URL.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
public class geckodriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\XXXX\\chromedriver.exe");



        driver.get("http://2048game.com");
       /* WebElement e1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]"));
        e1.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
        System.out.println("Done");
        Thread.sleep(15000);*/
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Solitaire Queen')]")).click();
        String url= driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println("url"+url);
        driver.quit();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL of the current page. Instantiate your driver and then get the driver's Url property.

Code snippet:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String currentURL =  driver.Url;
```

or,

```
driver.getLocation()
```